# Overlay and center images css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to create a banner of 3 images with a size of 900x420 like the picture at the bottom. Im wondering how can i get them aligned that each image is somehow centered horizontally. Any suggestion would be appreciated :
[image: a busy cat]

So far i have this with twitter bootstrap:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="img/rm1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="title-content">Caption goes here<h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="img/rm2.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="title-content">Caption goes here<h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="img/rm3.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="title-content">Caption goes here<h3>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-holder {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        background - color: rgba(2, 85, 165, 0.36);
    }
    .img-holder.caption {
        display: inline - block;
        position: absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/
        bottom: 0 px; /* position will be on bottom */
        left: 0 px;
        right: 0 px;
        width: 100 % ;
        /* styling bellow */
        background - color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
        color: white;
    }

h3.title_content {
    padding: 10 px;
    margin: 0 px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you have to give a width to the container-fluid to get the effect you want.

```css
.container-fluid{
  width:1400px; /* i used 450x210 image and 3 times 450 is 1350 hence i just used width 1400 */
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
.img-holder { 
float:left; 
position:relative;
background-color:rgba(2, 85, 165, 0.36);
} 
.img-holder .caption {
display:inline-block;
position:absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/  
bottom:0px; /* position will be on bottom */  
left:0px;
right: 0px;  
width:100%;  
/* styling bellow */  
background-color:rgba(120,120, 120, 0.36);
color:white;
}

h3.title_content{  
padding:10px;  
margin:0px; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/450x210/000/f23f1f.png" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="title-content">Caption goes here<h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/450x210/109/acdce2.png" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="title-content">Caption goes here<h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/450x210/036/0a34fe.png" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="title-content">Caption goes here<h3>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

I hope this was what you were expecting to do.

Comment: Well this is quiet close, but as you can see images are overlayed somehow that i dont think you need to specify a container's width. You can see that each image is 900x420, what changes is the way they are overlayed

Comment: do you mean to say that you want the caption to be in the center of the image?

Comment: No. Captions dont have anything to do here. Same thing you did in your example with an image size of 900x420 instead 450x210 need to have all images overlayed somehow they fix correctly

Comment: sorry I am not quite getting what you mean by overlay. To me overlay means it is laying on TOP of something else.

Comment: Thats right.. so how would you display 3 images of 900x420 in a 1400 screen width. Overlaying them i guess?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63731/discussion-between-andres-da-via-and-sai).

Answer (score -1):

use bottom code in your css code

```
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
```

Comment: and where do you propose OP add that css property?!